# Django not loading static files

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I created added a dashboard to my project it is using bootstrap files which I am trying to load but aren't loading.
I am trying to load static file using {% static '' %} and it's now picking up the files. You can ask for further code.

Here is the code of the template

```
    <link href=" {%static '../static/Dashboard/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" />


    <link href="{%static '../static/Dashboard/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css '%}" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <link href="{% static '../static/Dashboard/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href=" {%static '../static/Dashboard/assets/css/themify-icons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Setting in setting.py

```
STATICFILES_DIR=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    'final_project/static',
  ]


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Implement this code inside your project: Visit this link: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132733/how-run-static-file-when-debug-is-false>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In main folder of your project, create a folder named static. then in this folder create two other folders, named static_root and static_dirs

now change the settings.py file like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)
```

then add static files in static/static_dirs directory.

now you can use static files in your templates like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'Dashboard/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

your template should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <head>
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

**css/bootstrap.min.css** is in *final_project/static* directory

Do not forget add **{% load staticfiles %}**

Comment: Yup I have added {% load staticfiles %} and the path and everything is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py you define static path, then this way is incorrect:

```
<link href="{% static '../static/Dashboard/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

correct:

```
<link href="{% static 'Dashboard/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: how is it correct ? And it was the last thing i tried cuz I have tried everything almost!

Comment: Can I see your tree directory of your project?

Comment: I think your definition of static folder in settings.py is incorrect

Comment: The correct one you mentioned is not working you asked about.

Comment: I can tree it but it has 2620 directories, 6090 files how am i suppose to show you the whole tree??

Comment: I mean, I want to know where is the directory of static files relative to other directory in the project

Comment: It's in the main project directory.